# Matching AAAA records using iptables u32 module

Tags: iptables, dns

I need to match the two bytes four from the end of the UDP payload and check them against 0x001c. This would be easy if the UDP payload didn't have a variable length. How do I get the length of the UDP payload and jump to a byte relative to the END of the payload?

```
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m u32 --u32 "$foo" -j AAAA
```

I'd like to know what to put in `$foo` so that it matches outgoing AAAA queries and jumps to iptables target `AAAA`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `xt_u32` is the right tool for the job. You can do this more easily using `xt_bpf`:

```
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m bpf --bytecode "7,128 0 0 0,20 0 0 4,7 0 0 0,72 0 0 0,21 0 1 28,6 0 0 65535,6 0 0 0" -j AAAA
```

The bytecode comes from the following BPF assembly:

```
        ld #len            ; get the total length of the packet
        sub #4             ; subtract 4 to get the offset of the Type code
        tax                ; transfer the contents of register A to register X
        ldh [x + 0]        ; load the Type code (a half-word) into register A
        jneq #0x001c, fail ; check if Type == AAAA
        ret #65535         ; return success (match)
fail:   ret #0             ; return failure (no match)
```

I explain more about BPF in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/699504/164143).